# Преобразование массива из вида [,] в вид [][]

Tags: c#, массивы

Все никак не могу понять, есть ли какое-то явное преобразование массива вида double[,] в вид double[][], или все таки придется просто копировать в новый массив первый поэлементно.

Comment: Массив массивов и двухмерный массив - это разные типы. Думаю, придется копировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартных методов преобразования нет. Любой массив в принципе нельзя превратить в другой массив без копирования данных, а вот поэлементно копировать необязательно.

Думаю, это достаточно быстрый вариант.

```
static double[][] MatrixToJaggedArray(double[,] matrix)
{
    int rows = matrix.GetLength(0);
    int cols = matrix.GetLength(1);
    double[][] result = new double[rows][];
    int rowSize = sizeof(double) * cols;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        result[i] = new double[cols];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(matrix, i * rowSize, result[i], 0, rowSize);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Проверяю

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double[,] matrix = new double[,]
    {
        { 1.4, 2.3 },
        { 3.2, 4.1 } 
    };

    double[][] jaggedArray = MatrixToJaggedArray(matrix);
    for (int i = 0; i < jaggedArray.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", jaggedArray[i]));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
1,4 2,3
3,2 4,1
```

---

Обобщенная версия, работает со всеми [целочисленными](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types) и типами [с плавающей точкой](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types).

```
static T[][] MatrixToJaggedArray<T>(T[,] matrix) where T : unmanaged
{
    int rows = matrix.GetLength(0);
    int cols = matrix.GetLength(1);
    T[][] result = new T[rows][];
    int rowSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T)) * cols;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        result[i] = new T[cols];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(matrix, i * rowSize, result[i], 0, rowSize);
    }
    return result;
}
```